# git-svn pass password on command-line

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

Is it possible to pass the SVN password on the command-line or in a text file?  I would like to run git-svn via a script?

I know that the username can be passed on the command-line, but is it possible to pass the password as well or have it stored in another location that git-svn can use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Git-svn can use the credentials defined in the `~/.subversion/servers` file.

Comment: I will give that another go-round.

Answer (score 15):

You can use:

```
echo $password | git svn --username $username ...
```